# step by step installation phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 16.04 (Access denied while installing phpmyadmin)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

There is " Access denied for user" in the process of installing phpmyadmin in Ubuntu 16.04.

Ubuntu 16.04, phpmyadmin (4:4.5.4.1-2ubuntu2), mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7,mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7

1. mysql-server (only data I povide):
   [image]

Rest of images come from phpmyadmin:

2.
[image]
3.
[image]
4.
[image]
5.
[image]
6.
[image]
7.
[image]
8.
[image]
9.

[image]
10.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please fire following command and solve your problem 100%

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql*
sudo apt-get --purge remove phpmyadmin
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server phpmyadmin php-gettext php-mbstring
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: You could maybe be a bit more elaborate about what commands do what.